# React-Native https URL в WebView без ssl сертификата

Tags: java, ios, reactjs, ssl, react-native

Всем привет. Я недавно начал изучать react-native и решил сделать небольшое приложение с BE на java и FE на react-native. Но возникла проблема. Я сконфигурировал подключение по https но WebView форма не хочет открывать URL c self-signature сертификатом и выдает ошибку NSURLErrorDomain -1202.
Сделать настоящий сертификат я не могу, так как разворачиваюсь только на localhost, домена нет. 
Если какая то возможность отключить проверку на валидность сертификата?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Пробема решена с помощью

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>linkedin.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

и использования WKWebView from 'react-native-wkwebview-reborn'